# 500 (Internal Server Error) while using ajax codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, internal-server-error

I am getting error `jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/Speakertest/index.php/Welcome/ajax 500 (Internal Server Error)`

I am calling ajax function in codeigniter

after adding query I am getting error https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfxVd.png

this is my ajax function code

```
    public function ajax()
{



    $size="";
    $eprice="";

    $size = $this->input->post('size');
    $sprice = $this->input->post('sprice');
    $eprice = $this->input->post('eprice');

    var_dump($size);
    var_dump($sprice);
    var_dump($eprice);


      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from info_user Where user_status ='1'"); 

                  if(!empty($size)){

                      $query  .= $this->db->query(" and city in('$size')"); 
                  }

                  if(!empty($sprice) && !empty($eprice)){

                      $query  .=  $this->db->query(" and charge_per_hour >='$sprice' and charge_per_hour <='$eprice'"); 
                  }

                foreach( $result as $row )
                {

                            echo $row->name; 
                            echo $row->charge_per_hour; 
                            echo $row->city; 

                 }
}
```

this is the lines which generates error

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from info_user Where user_status ='1'"); 

                  if(!empty($size)){

                      $query  .= $this->db->query(" and city in('$size')"); 
                  }

                  if(!empty($sprice) && !empty($eprice)){

                      $query  .=  $this->db->query(" and charge_per_hour >='$sprice' and charge_per_hour <='$eprice'"); 
                  }

                foreach( $result as $row )
                {

                            echo $row->name; 
                            echo $row->charge_per_hour; 
                            echo $row->city; 

                 }
```

and this is my ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost/Speakertest/index.php/Welcome/ajax",
            type:'post',
            data:{size:size,sprice:ui.values[ 0 ],eprice:ui.values[ 1 ]},
            success:function(result){
                $('.product-data').html(result);
            }
        });
```

after removing that mysql query it working fine. how to rid that POST http://localhost/Speakertest/index.php/Welcome/ajax 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Using `$query  .= $this->db->query(...)` isn't going to work, you need to build the query string first.

Comment: that whole code was on core php I covert it in codeignitor.. In codeignitor how to concatenate multiple query ???  `$query .=` Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code with this

```
    $query = "SELECT * from info_user Where user_status ='1'"; 
    if(!empty($size)){
        $query  .= " and city in('".$size."')"; 
    }
    if(!empty($sprice) && !empty($eprice)){
        $query  .=  " and charge_per_hour >='".$sprice."' and 
        charge_per_hour <='".$eprice."'"; 
    }

     $result = $this->db->query($query);

     foreach( $result as $row )
     {
         echo $row->name; 
         echo $row->charge_per_hour; 
         echo $row->city; 
     }
```

Comment: hey after trying this code I got this error. I tried to encounter the error. but I couldn't [click me](https://i.imgur.com/CajUIO4.png)  and line number 35 is this one `$query  .=  " and charge_per_hour >='".$sprice."' and charge_per_hour <='".$eprice."'"); ` please have a look

Comment: $query  .=  " and charge_per_hour >='".$sprice."' and 
        charge_per_hour <='".$eprice."'"; remove last parenthesis before semicolon